# Choose N samples from dataset for best distribution

Tags: algorithm, statistics, distribution

This question may have been asked before, but I couldn't find it. I am not sure how to word it properly.
My situation is this:

I have a large dataset and I want to choose a subset of samples that best represents the data.

To be more specific, I have many points within a unit (hyper)cube, and I want to choose N points that have the widest/smoothest coverage.

I'm thinking this must be a well known problem (for example, colour quantisation). However, there is one extra constraint. The N samples must be members of the original dataset, not mean values of a cluster or anything like that.

Also, I don't care about efficiency, accuracy is far more important.

Thanks.

Comment: Need a more precise definition of what kind of coverage you want to achieve.  Do you want to ensure that the points chosen maximize the distance between points within the dataset? Or that they cover the widest range of values on each dimension of the cube? Or something else? -- and why is it so important that you fit the chosen  constraint most accurately? What will the chosen points be used for?

Comment: A simple random sample should be sufficient to get unbiased estimates of population parameters.